# Want to make Func<UnknownType, bool> where UnknownType is only known at runtime

Tags: c#, expression, func

So, I'm experimenting with expressions atm. Got code below:
Code works fine except for 1 thing: I need to replace ViewModel type with ForeignKeyProperty.PropertyType, which is only known at runtime, at the line of `var condition = Expression.Lambda < Func < ViewModel, bool> >`

Expected end result:

```
ForeignKeyProperty.SetValue(model, repository.GetList  <ForeignKeyProperty.PropertyType >().Single(x => x.Id == model.Id));

protected List < Action < IVenturaRepository, ViewModel>> SetForeignKeyProperties<ViewModel>() where ViewModel : BaseViewModel
        {
            var viewModelType = typeof(ViewModel);
            var foreignKeyProperties = viewModelType.GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseViewModel)));
            var actions = new List < Action < IVenturaRepository, ViewModel>>();
            var repositoryType = typeof(IVenturaRepository);
            foreach(var ForeignKeyProperty in foreignKeyProperties)
            {
                var foreignKeyIdProperty = viewModelType.GetProperties().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == ForeignKeyProperty.Name + "Id");
                //ForeignKeyProperty.SetValue(model, repository.GetList<ViewModel>().Single(x => x.Id == model.Id));
                var listMethod = repositoryType.GetMethods().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "GetList").MakeGenericMethod(ForeignKeyProperty.PropertyType);
                //Expression.Call(singleMethod,);
                var repositoryVariable = Expression.Parameter(repositoryType, "repository");
                var paramViewModelType = Expression.Parameter(viewModelType, "model");
                var paramForeignEntityId = Expression.Property(paramViewModelType, "Id");
                var listMethodCall = Expression.Call(repositoryVariable, listMethod);
                var modelParameter = Expression.Parameter(ForeignKeyProperty.PropertyType, "x");
                var foreignKeyTypeConstant = Expression.Constant(ForeignKeyProperty.PropertyType);
                var condition =
                    Expression.Lambda < Func < ViewModel, bool>>(
                        Expression.Equal(
                            Expression.Property(paramViewModelType, foreignKeyIdProperty.Name),
                            Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(modelParameter, "Id"),foreignKeyIdProperty.PropertyType)
                        ),
                        modelParameter
                    );
                //var singleMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals("SingleOrDefault") && x.GetParameters().Count() ==2).MakeGenericMethod(viewModelType);
                //var singleMethod = typeof(IEnumerable<ViewModel>).GetMethods().SingleOrDefault(x => x.GetParameters().Count() > 0).MakeGenericMethod(viewModelType);
                //var singleLambda = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(modelParameter, "Id"), modelParameter);
                var singleMethodCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "SingleOrDefault", new[] { ForeignKeyProperty.PropertyType },listMethodCall, condition);
                //var singleMethodCall = Expression.Call(listMethodCall, singleMethod, condition);
                var setMethod = ForeignKeyProperty.GetSetMethod();
                var oParameter = Expression.Parameter(viewModelType, "obj");
                var vParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ViewModel),"value");
                var method = Expression.Call(oParameter,setMethod, singleMethodCall);
                var expression = Expression.Lambda<Action<IVenturaRepository, ViewModel>>(method);
                actions.Add(expression.Compile());
            }
            return actions;
        }
```

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Closing a generic has to happen at compile time. It is not possible to do it at runtime.

Comment: The l thing that expects a Func<UnknownType, bool> needs to be written in accordance with whatever that type is. If it really doesn't matter then you can pass func<object, bool>. If it does, you could pass func<ISomeInterface, bool>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I did as you suggested and used object instead. It works now.
Code below works in a specific controller that inherits from BaseController.

`public override ActionResult Edit(long id, DeliveryEditViewModel model)
        {
            model.SourceModel.DeliveryRound = Repository.DeliveryRounds.Single(x => x.Id == model.DeliveryRoundId);
            model.SourceModel.Sale = Repository.Sales.Single(x => x.Id == model.SaleId);
            return base.Edit(id, model);
        }`

Idea is that code below works in BaseController:

        `public virtual ActionResult Edit(long id, EditModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                if (setForeignKeyActionList == null)
                    setForeignKeyActionList = SetForeignKeyProperties();
                setForeignKeyActionList.ForEach(action => action(Repository, model.SourceModel));
                Repository.SaveItem(model);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error", ex);
                return View(Repository.GetEditableItem(id));
            }
        }`

This is the revised code based on your suggestion to use object type

`protected List< Action< IVenturaRepository, ViewModel>> SetForeignKeyProperties()
        {
            var viewModelType = typeof(ViewModel);
            var foreignKeyProperties = viewModelType.GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseViewModel)));
            var actions = new List< Action< IVenturaRepository, ViewModel>>();
            var repositoryType = typeof(IVenturaRepository);
            foreach (var ForeignKeyProperty in foreignKeyProperties)
            {
                var foreignKeyIdProperty = viewModelType.GetProperties().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == ForeignKeyProperty.Name + "Id");
                //ForeignKeyProperty.SetValue(model, repository.GetList< OtherViewModel>().Single(x => x.Id == model.Id));
                var listMethod = repositoryType.GetMethods().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "GetList").MakeGenericMethod(ForeignKeyProperty.PropertyType);
                var repositoryVariable = Expression.Parameter(repositoryType, "repository");
                var paramViewModelType = Expression.Parameter(viewModelType, "model");
                var paramForeignEntityId = Expression.Property(paramViewModelType, "Id");
                var listMethodCall = Expression.Call(repositoryVariable, listMethod);`

```
            var foreignKeyTypeConstant = Expression.Constant(ForeignKeyProperty.PropertyType);
            var objectType = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "model");
            var modelParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "x");
            var expressionForeignKeyId = Expression.Property(paramViewModelType, foreignKeyIdProperty.Name);
            var expressionForeignEntityId = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(Expression.Convert(modelParameter, ForeignKeyProperty.PropertyType), "Id"), foreignKeyIdProperty.PropertyType);
            var condition =
                Expression.Lambda<Func<object, bool>>(
                    Expression.Equal(
                        expressionForeignKeyId,
                        expressionForeignEntityId
                    ),
                    modelParameter
                );
            var singleMethodCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "SingleOrDefault", new[] { ForeignKeyProperty.PropertyType }, listMethodCall, condition);
            //var singleMethodCall = Expression.Call(listMethodCall, singleMethod, condition);
            var setMethod = ForeignKeyProperty.GetSetMethod();
            //var oParameter = Expression.Parameter(viewModelType, "obj");
            var vParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ViewModel), "value");
            var method = Expression.Call(paramViewModelType, setMethod, singleMethodCall);
            var lamdaParameterExpressions = new[]
            {
                repositoryVariable,
                paramViewModelType
            };
            var expression = Expression.Lambda<Action<IVenturaRepository, ViewModel>>(method, lamdaParameterExpressions);
            actions.Add(expression.Compile());
        }
        return actions;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use Object as type. then you can check type by getType() at runtime and after check cast to correct type. or use dynamic to avoid casting.